# Linksys AE1200 USB WiFi adapter driver not working properly with W10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

Since upgrading to W10, I am having problems with Linksys AE1200 wireless adapter. It keeps dropping connection after a few minutes (sometimes it works for some time like 15 minutes and more). There is no difference if you are using the connection or not (surfing/downloading/uploading/etc), it just drops. It does not show there is no connection, but there is none. Nor websites nor ping works. I have to unplug the USB and plug it in again (or disable/re-enable it) for it to work. I found some threads on the internet but i found no solution, except if solutions is just calling it "unredeemable piece of garbage".

One of the threads:
http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/ae1200-loses-connection-after-15-minutes.60365/

I have found that some WiFi USB adapters have unofficial adapters, but not for this model. Is it possible i failed to find it? Website with such drivers: https://sites.google.com/site/linksysupdateddrivers/linksys-wireless-network-adapters-with-ralink-chipsets

So is there any solution to this? Did anyone else experience the same problems? Will I (or anyone else, while we're at it) be ever able to use this WiFi adapter with Windows 10?

Comment: Could someone explain me why a question about a specific piece of hardware and a specific OS is being closed as "too broad"?

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice.